# Is there any hashing function which generates same results for nearly similar input?

Tags: hash, rabin-karp, plagiarism-detection, lsh

I want to implement a problem solution that requires a hashing function that returns the same output for similar input. The input will be some code and I want the hashing function to ignore the variable names, etc.

If no such hashing function is available then how can I implement this using other hashing algorithms. Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

Most hashing functions are designed to do the opposite: If the input is different, even a tiny bit, they will most likely return a completely different value.

But maybe you could "normalize" your input first. Replace each unique variable name with a string, e.g. the first variable name with `"var00000001"`, the next with `"var00000002"`, etc. in the order of their first appearance.